# Can I use Lazarus Pascal to build for iOS AND Android

Tags: android, ios, mobile, lazarus

I would like to know:

1. If it's possible to use Lazarus (Pascal) for both Android and iOS development.
2. If the answer seems positive, do I need a third-party SDK/API or package to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Android: See answer from Nic Strong.
- iOS (iPhone/iPad): Check google and [find](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/iPhone/iPod_development) this result.

Comment: So, after looking at the links from you and Nic, it seems like a YES with a NO :)
i.e., to say, yes, we can use Lazarus/FP but no, there are issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am almost certain the answer is no.

EDIT: Looks like I was wrong. See http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Android_Programming

Comment: Thanks for the tip. And do you think it can be used for the iOS?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. For Ios Lazurs uses objectivepascal which a pascal extension that allows integration with objective-c much like objective-c++. 
However it is necessary to do some work to set-up the environment and you need an Apple computer to build test and debug.

This is the best entry point for iOS development:

http://objectivepascal.com/

Comment: Have you done this on a regular basis or at least to build a real-world app? A lot of folks who say "yes you can" also say "but there's some work to do to get it going" but they've never really tried this for real.

Comment: We had a discussion on linked in about this and there was a ready solution for IOS. But now it seems to be missing. Here's the linked in discussion: https://www.linkedin.com/groups/iOS-development-Lazarus-4558772.S.273351327